# Finding element using Xpath worked in IE9 but not in IE11

Tags: selenium

[Attached is the HTML SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFsFG.png) I am trying to click a button in my application. The button text is " Reassign". Please note that there is a space before the text. The space is visible when looking in developer tool in IE9. But not in IE11. I am unable to find the element in IE11. Whereas a simple

Driver.findelement(By.xpath(".//button[text()=' Reassign']")).click()

Worked in IE9. Same statement is not working in IE11.

Comment: Different browsers have different rendering engines. Have you tried using `contains()`?

Comment: try to update selenium dll from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Yes. I tried contains() as well. And I downloaded the latest selenium dll. But the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Driver.findelement(By.xpath(".//button[text()=' Reassign']")).click()
```

you could try

```
Driver.findelement(By.xpath(".//button[normalize-space(text())='Reassign']")).click()
```

This will ignore any leading or trailing whitespaces.

Comment: The below XPATH is working though, 

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='page_SubNavigation']/div[2]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/button[1]")`

But I am looking for taking the XPATH in a more correct way. The tags may change in future.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Please refer the attached screenshot of my HTML page for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `By.linkText()` could help, as Microsoft may have implemented it different than `By.xpath()`.

Try both `By.linkText('Reassign')` and `By.linkText(' Reassign')`. If neither works, try `By.partialLinkText('Reassign')`. This is of course not as specific, but, depending on your page, could do.

Comment: linkText and partialLinkText did not work either Kimmy.

Comment: Too bad! No idea, then.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below xpath works

//div[@class='divbuttonholder margin-left-none margin- top1']/table/tbody/tr/td/button[@type='button'][@data-bind='click:$root.Reassign']